# How to consume different request bodies in one endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to build a service that needs to consume different xmlTypes in request body of one endpoint.

To do so, I've implemented this:

```
    @PostMapping(value="/one")
    public ResponseEntity<?> result(
            String xmlType,
            @RequestBody Object body
    ) {
        Employe employee = null; // employee object that is generated by xsd file.
        Profile profile = null; // profile object that is generated by xsd file.
        if (body instanceof Employe) {
            employee = (Employe) body;
        } else if (body instanceof Profile) {
            profile = (Profile) body;
        }
        
        // business logic 

        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    }
```

but by this implementation, I'm getting *Unsupported Media Type* error.

**Example usage of the service;**

- url: '/domain/one?xmlType=Profile', body(requestBody): `<Profile></Profile>`
- url: '/domain/one?xmlType=Employee', body(requestBody): `<Employee></Employee>`

When I use the specific Object it works, but I couldn't implement the generic version. So, how can I achieve this feature?

Comment: use request method like get put post delete patch or pass a flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use two methods and narrow the request mapping thanks to [`params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/one", params = "xmlType=Profile")
public ResponseEntity<?> postProfile(@RequestBody Profile body) {
    ...
}

@PostMapping(value = "/one", params = "xmlType=Employee")
public ResponseEntity<?> postEmployee(@RequestBody Employee body) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a good question.

How about creating an empty DTO class with the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation?